# Ring theoretic properties of integer valued poynomials.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let us denote by $A$ the ring of integer-valued polynomials in $\mathbf{Q}[T]$.
We know that $A$ is not Noetherian and of dimension $2$. I would like to understand $A$ better, for instance
(a) what is the homological dimension of $A$?
(b) I think the fibre ring $A\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{Z}/p$ should be related to the $p$-adic integers, can someone point out this connection?

Comment: $A \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}} \mathbf{Z}/p$ is simply $A/p$.

Comment: Moreover, I suspect that $A/p \cong (\mathbf{Z}/p)^p$.

Comment: https://math.osu.edu/sites/math.osu.edu/files/steward_polynomials_2015.pdf Theorem 4.2